# ASP.NET exception handling tools

Tags: asp.net, exception

I currently have a C# ASP.NET application and would like to start handling exceptions in a smart, unified way.

What tools or Nuget packages are recommended for this? Things like ELMAH.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by handling , do you want to log the exceptions to file or db

Answer (score 0):

For exceptions, `ELMAH` is best for unhandled exceptions, in my experience. Whereas `Log4Net` is good for logging purpose because it is very configurable in multiple different ways and purposes.

For more info, check this out: 
https://www.loggly.com/blog/benchmarking-5-popular-net-logging-libraries/
[Which log utility is good for .NET application in C# (ASP.NET, WinForms)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107546/which-log-utility-is-good-for-net-application-in-c-sharp-asp-net-winforms)