# WCF Message Logging and Tracking

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, error-logging

I have a WCF service which communicates with Magento Web service and writes the data into the tables.
I would like to set up a logging system in my project which would write to a log file saying what data was inserted into which table at what time and probably the error message as well on failure.
Presently i have enabled the tracer which logs the requests made by the application to the webs ervice.

Comment: It is a bit unclear what is actually being asked; does your current solution work as desired?

Comment: the solution works perfectly, extracting data from the web service. I just need to set up a logging logic which would have data like how many rows were inserted or how long the unit test ran and if at all it failed, at what time and in which method.

Comment: From your comment, it seems that the question is actually unrelated to WCF.

Comment: The entire solution is WCF based

Comment: Seems you need to look into a logging framework? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185542/net-logging-framework I personally like log4net.  I recommend you stay away from the Enterprise logging library.